# Facing problem in using tensorflow (js) in react native cli (not in expo cli)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

When ever i install the dependencies of tensorflow in react native cli and do number of changes in android files even then the app doesn't run due to some issue in @unimodules/react-native-adapter . Does anyone know the right way to work with tensorflow in react native cli (not in expo cli)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.